# Libgdx ghost vertices help using box2d

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, box2d

I read this article http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices which explained a solution to my box2d bodies getting stuck at the intersections of multiple small fixtures supposed to be making up a platform and it says to use EdgeShapes to use the ghost vertices but after rereading a few times I am still very confused as to how to apply this ghost vertices method of solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghost vertices are automatically calculated in libgdx so you don't get stuck in the ground. I had the same problem. Instead of using rectangles use EdgeShape and put in the vertices instead and you'll be fine!

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understood, ghost vertices are ignored by the collission detection, but treated like normal edges by the collission response.
So if you collide with the "main-edge", the calculation of the collission response starts. Here, there is no "main-edge" anymore. Instead the ghost-vertex (the one, closer to the collision point), forms a new, continuous shape, together with the "main-edge".
So i guess, the ghost vertices can be like the adjacent edges, simmulating a continuous plattform.
This solution actually should solve the problem, while other solutions are only some kind of workarround, which in many cases are enough.
You could, for example, try to "cut" the edges or use a circle shape if possible. In some situations it might be enough.

Comment: Thank you and I understand that part I am just at a loss as to how to implement it in code is what I ment

Comment: As the article says, you need to give a value for m_vertex0 and m_vertex3 of the edge, and set m_hasVertex0 and m_hasVertex3 to true.